# Execute current line in shell

Tags: shell

I often find myself copying commands line by line from an emacs buffer to my terminal.

How do i bind a shortcut which sends the current line/selection in emacs to my gnome-terminal?

Comment: isend-mode seems to do the trick...

Comment: thx for the hint. I haven't found something and wrote a function by myself. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: well, the question might still be relevant as emacs terminal emulators are not as good as gnome-terminal (think vim or less). Ideally those commands would be sent to a gnome-terminal window

Comment: Indeed. I'd sure be interested in that solution.

Comment: There is also more sophisticated `eepitch` functionality in `eev` package.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, running commands in existing terminals isn't something all terminals support ([at least not without some hackery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156328/63928)), this seems something you might use screen or tmux for.

Also this isn't really related to emacs - if you find a way to do this - the following snippet could be easily modified.

Edit, it seems roxterm supports this, edited answer.

The following answer opens a new terminal.

---

Here is a small script which takes the selection (or current line) and runs it in gnome-terminal.

```elisp
(defun shell-command-on-region-or-line ()
  "Run selected text in a terminal or use the current line."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command
   (concat

    ;; pick one!
    "gnome-terminal -e "
    ; "roxterm --tab -e "
    ; "terminator -x "

    (if (use-region-p)
        ;; current selection
        (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))
        ;; current line
        (thing-at-point 'line t)))))
```

Example key binding you wont hit by accident :)

```
;; Execute text in a terminal, no questions! (ctrl-alt-shift-enter to avoid accidents!)
(global-set-key (kbd "<c-m-s-return>") 'term-shell-command-on-region-or-line)
```

---

Note, I ended up finding this quite useful and made it into a package that has some option prefixes for opening in different ways, including path detection:

https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-run-stuff

Comment: tried it with both the above version and termite, terminator etc and dosent seem to open any term window

Comment: @zeltak terminator works here, added commented text to use.

Comment: thx @ideasman42. do now it does open terminator but the highlighted command dosent seem to run in the new terminator window. what i get is a new buffer in emas with the actual command, ie if i stand over 'ls' and launch the function it opens a new empty terminator window and a buffer in emacs wit the contents of ls

Comment: I don't get the new buffer, but it does open a new terminal, edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options within Emacs. M-! opens a minibuffer, which allows you to type or paste shell commands into it, and puts the results in another buffer. C-u M-! will do the same thing but insert the result directly into the buffer. There is also M-| which pipes a region to a shell command but I'm never used it.